# facebook comment page - object missing a required value

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I try to post a facebook comment in a simple empty page, i got message error popup :

"object missing a required value"

Here is the page : http://mobile.codinghero.net/haltaalam/comments.php?idimage=2&iduser=1

Someone know the reason?

Thanks for helping me

Comment: Works fine for me, at least in Firefox.

Comment: try to change idimage for example http://mobile.codinghero.net/haltaalam/comments.php?idimage=160&iduser=1 and test again, you will see eror message and your comment will not be posted

Comment: My “test” comment shows up, but yes, I get the error message (interestingly with a few seconds delay, after I see my comment show up.) But the comment is still there, even after I reload the page. / It might have to do with the fact that Facebook has not scraped the URL yet - after I put it through https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug once, I can not reproduce that error any more.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same issue. It seems to be to do with the parameters in the url:

For example, this url **works**:
www.example.com/shop/id/999/

But this url **does not work**:
www.example.com/shop/?id=999

However, if you add the file extension, you can use parameters:
This **works**:
www.example.com/shop/index.php?id=999

However, doing the same with an HTML file **does not work**:
www.example.com/shop/index.html?id=999

The error only occurs on the first post, there after it behaves normally.
Also as CBroe has said, the post is still made when the error shows, you just have to refresh the page to see it.

Comment: Your answer is helpful - while the 'link' is only a parameter for facebook script, it can be easily stripped of non-working part. It's just to identify webpage with comments. Works as a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the og properties are set in the head section.

I was getting this error, but only on the first post just like pureth above (I kept having to change the name of my page to test).

Example:

```
<meta property="og:url"                content="https://www.scabard.com/page/FB_Comment_Callback_Test_5/simple" />
<meta property="og:type"               content="article" />
<meta property="og:title"              content="FB Comment Callback Test" />
<meta property="og:description"        content="Test callback when posting comment" />
<meta property="og:image"              content="http://alltherex.com/admin/uploads/movies/B00005JN4W.jpg" />
```

Got the answer from here: http://thestateofart.com/object-missing-a-required-value-facebook-comment/